# No messages to Rails 4 production log Apache/Phusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I am getting no messages written to the production log using Rails 4.0.2 and Phusion Passenger 4.0.46.

I have checked file permissions and `production.log` is owned by the user I'm running as and has write permissions. `touch production.log` works fine. Deleting the file and getting a page from the site recreates the file (0 bytes)

log levels are set to `:info` in the `environments/production.rb`
`Rails.logger.info("test message")` returns true but no message written

I have checked previous answers and tried:

`Rails.logger.instance_variable_get(:@logger).instance_variable_get(:@log_dest).sync = true if Rails.logger` (supposedly not needed in Rails 4 but just in case it was a regression...)

I get the message `NoMethodError: undefined method`sync=' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Is there anything in apache's global log?

Comment: No, nothing out of the ordinary logging of the gets, posts, etc. Nothing helpful there that I can see.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm seeing this behavior both on the deployed site on a shared hosting account and also on my local development machine. But on my local machine, using thin, I see logger.info entries written to STDOUT on the terminal where thin is running. Is there some sort of extra config to get those messages to also write to production.log?  It all works fine in development mode.  Also continues to re-create a 0 byte production.log after I delete it.

Comment: did you ever solve it?  as a workaround, i created a rails initializer that does `Rails.logger= Logger.new('log/production.log') if Rails.env.production?` if i put that code in `production.rb` it was getting overridden back to `STDOUT`